# Finding all entire functions satisfying $\text{Re}(g(z))+2\text{Re}(z)=\text{Im}(g(z))$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have been asked to...

> Find all entire functions $g$ such that $\forall z\in\mathbb{C}$ we have $\text{Re}(g(z))+2\text{Re}(z)=\text{Im}(g(z))$ satisfied.

Now, since $g$ is entire, it has to satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations on all of $\mathbb{C}$. Also, writing $g(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$, with $x\equiv \text{Re}(z)$ and $y\equiv \text{Im}(z)$, for some real functions $u$ and $v$, we find that
\begin{align}
u(x,y) + 2x = v(x,y),
\end{align}
and thus that 
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\bigg[ u(x,y) +2x \bigg] = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + 2.
\end{align}
Applying the Cauchy-Riemann equations, we find
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} =-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} &= \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + 2  \\
\Rightarrow \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} &= -2.
\end{align}

This, however, doesnt really seem to help a lot. I am unsure how to proceed. Any hints would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Differentiating your first line with respect to y gives:

$${\partial u\over\partial y}={\partial v\over\partial y}={\partial u\over\partial x}$$.

The last equation follows from the Cauchy-Riemann equations. Should be easy now by combining with your result.

Comment: This gives me that $\partial u / \partial x = -1$, in other words that $u(x,y)=-x+$ some function of $y$. And that $\partial u / \partial y = -1\ \Rightarrow \ u(x,y)=-y +$ some function of $x$. Thus $u(x,y)=-x-y$ giving (by the condition in the exercise) $v(x,y)=x-y$. So $g(z) = -z+iz$? Does this make sense?

Comment: I don't have the work for this with me at the moment, but I got $g(z)=2z+C$ with $C$ a complex constant. I'll get back to you in a few minutes.

Comment: Silly error on my part. The hint is valid, but $2z+C$ is not.

Comment: Yes $-z+iz+C$ is correct.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot, sir. :)

Comment: Note that $C$ cannot be an *arbitrary* complex constant (compare with my answer).

Comment: @Morten Yes, good point.

Answer (score 2):

Using $\text{Im}(w) = -\text{Re}(iw)$, your condition is equivalent to

$$
    \text{Re}(g(z))+2\text{Re}(z) = \text{Re}(ig(z))
$$
or
$$ 
   \text{Re}\bigl(g(z) + 2z + ig(z)\bigr) = 0 \, .
$$
A holomorphic function in a domain is uniquely determined by its real part
up to a constant, this can easily be seen by applying the Cauchy-Riemann
equations to $h(z) := g(z) + 2z + ig(z)$.

Therefore
$$
    g(z) + 2z + ig(z) = iC \quad \text{for some } C \in \mathbb R \, .
$$
Solving this for $g$ gives
$$
   g(z) = (-1+i)z + \frac12 (1+i)C 
$$
or
$$
   g(z) = (-1+i)z + (1+i)D \quad\text{for some } D \in \mathbb R \, .
$$